# Getting Service Insight to connect to Management Service

Tags: nservicebus, serviceinsight

My OS is a Windows 2012 Essentials.

I installed NServiceBus 4 using the installer, then installed Service Insight.
Accepted the default settings.

When I start up Service Insight, there is an error about connecting to the management service.  I've tried putting in `http://localhost:3333` but that errors out to a 404. I've verified that the service "particular management" is running.

EDIT

As per Hadi's instructions, I've pasted the url he listed: `http://localhost:33333/api` into the `Connect to Management Service -> Service URL` text box, but it still has a 404 not found error. When I try putting the URL into google chrome, I also get a 404 (with graphics courtesy of the oatmeal).

I've verified that a service named `Particular Management` is running. The description of the service is `Particular Management Service for NServiceBus (Version 4.0.5)`.

I've ran the installer again to get to the modify/repair/remove options and verified in the modify option that the management service is installed.

Is there supposed to be a different service called `Management Service`? Is this maybe an issue introduced with version 4.0.5?

EDIT 2
I've appended the extra `/` to the end of the url, still no dice. This here is the logging information.

```
2013-10-11 09:15:58,488 - [INFO ] - IManagementService - HTTP GET http://localhost:33333/api//
2013-10-11 09:15:58,501 - [DEBUG] - IManagementService - HTTP Status NotFound (404) (http://localhost:33333/api//http://localhost:33333/api)
2013-10-11 09:15:58,506 - [DEBUG] - IManagementService - Response Header: Transfer-Encoding : chunked
2013-10-11 09:15:58,507 - [DEBUG] - IManagementService - Response Header: X-Particular-Version : 1.0.0-unstable122
2013-10-11 09:15:58,508 - [DEBUG] - IManagementService - Response Header: Cache-Control : private, max-age=300, must-revalidate
2013-10-11 09:15:58,509 - [DEBUG] - IManagementService - Response Header: Content-Type : text/html
2013-10-11 09:15:58,529 - [DEBUG] - IManagementService - Response Header: Date : Fri, 11 Oct 2013 14:15:58 GMT
2013-10-11 09:15:58,533 - [DEBUG] - IManagementService - Response Header: Server : Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
2013-10-11 09:15:58,536 - [ERROR] - IManagementService - Error executing the request: , Status code is NotFound
```

Comment: I also have the same problem across machines...I get a 400 though.

Answer (score 1):

You need the slash at the end:
`http://localhost:33333/api/`

Comment: I tried appending the extra slash, no dice, I've added the log of the error, perhaps that will help?

Answer (score 0):

The Url to Service Control (a.k.a Management Service) also needs /api, e.g. `http://localhost:33333/api` (you missed a 3?). At the end of the day, it is also a NServiceBus host process, so you need to check and make sure it is actually running (using Task Manager, or Services).

Comment: I've updated my OP with additional troubleshooting information, long story short, the url didn't work. FYI, i didn't modify the defaults during the installation.

Comment: I don't get a 404. When I point my browser to the Url I get a Json object back, which is supposed to be your help. It gives you a list of endpoints you can use and their required parameters.